# Сравнивание двух mp3 файлов на Java

Tags: java, mp3

Мне нужно сравнить файлы на сходство в процентах. Например, если у нас есть записано слово "ок" и мы берем другой файл, где записано тоже слово (не тот же файл) и нам нужно сравнить оба файла на сходство если, например, сходство больше 70% тогда выводим что в файлах хранится одинаковые слова.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать на Java (возможно, классы для декодировки mp3 файлов)?

Comment: Что именно вам нужно сравнивать в файлах? Простейшая проверка хэшей покажет одинаковы файлы или нет, что вполне может быть решением проблемы.

Comment: Вообще-то [mp3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) файлы предназначены для хранения *аудиоинформации* (естественно, кроме нее там есть служебные данные разметки и *теги*). Что именно из содержащегося в них надо сравнивать?